# Setting up an Ubuntu Email Server

Tags: server, email

I just configured an Ubuntu 14.04 email server using Postfix and Dovecot with also setting up Squirrelmail.  I'm having some issues logging into the server though.  I've been at this for hours trying to figure this out.  I followed through [this tutorial](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/).  I followed everything correctly and it appears that the server is running, but I cannot configure Thunderbird to login, though it finds the server.  Both Thunderbird and Squirrelmail fail during the authentication/login step.  I have no idea what's going on with the login.  I have been attempting to create a new user and set it's permissions correctly as advised in [this](http://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/) tutorial at step 15 ...but no luck.

Comment: Hint: Check your ports..

Comment: I did, all my ports are opened up on my router. Ubuntu server is also listening on all ports necessary also. Is there another way to open up port directly in  Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Ok, I can now login to Squirrelmail but now get this error: "ERROR:
ERROR: Could not complete request.
Query: SELECT "INBOX"
Reason Given: [SERVERBUG] Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2015-06-08 01:44:36]"  and still unable to access via Thunderbird

Comment: Have you checked the server log

Comment: It looks like I'm getting a permission denied at the /home/nastylucas/ folder..and the subsequent mail folder as well.

Comment: Wait, I think I know how to fix that, let me add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nmap` `netstat` and `ufw` to check if required ports are open and not blocked by any firewall. If you're sure there's no problem with ports and firewall, then try below:-

```
cd /home/user/mail/domain.com/email_account/
```

Then, check if a **tmp** folder is present using:-

```
ls -ld tmp/
```

If, not then create a tmp folder:-

```
mkdir tmp
```

Check r/w permissions and ownership of the temp and the **.inbox** folder.

**NOTE:-** Follow the same above steps if you're unable to access other mailbox (draft etc.).

Comment: thanks, I will try that now. Now quick questions, I'm new at linux, so how do I check the ownership of the folders?

Comment: Using `ls -ld` , you can check the ownership of the folder that you're in. To change ownership, use `chown owner`.

Comment: Here's the error I get when trying to access the directory: email9000@quicksilver:~$ cd /home/nastylucas/mail/quicksilver.dontexist.net/nastylucas@quicksilver.dontexist.net
-bash: cd: /home/nastylucas/mail/quicksilver.dontexist.net/nastylucas@quicksilver.dontexist.net: Permission denied

Comment: Here is the permissions for the dir: email9000@quicksilver:/home/nastylucas$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 3 nastylucas nastylucas 4096 Jun  8 01:44 .

Comment: you need to `$ cd /home/email9000` if you're gonna use email9000 as the account for mail server.

Comment: ok, I'm checking that right now. But what if I wanted to have multiple users? Such as the nastylucas acct?

Comment: Its already there, just login using nastylucas@quicksilver.dontexist.net

Comment: I have tired multiple times...in both Squirrelmail and thunder bird. Squirrel Mail gives the error: ERROR: Could not complete request.
Query: SELECT "INBOX"
Reason Given: [SERVERBUG] Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2015-06-08 02:26:33] and Thudnerbird fails authentication.  I check the  logs and I see permission issues to access the home directory

Comment: On the server, logout and login as nastylucas

Comment: Getting an Access Denied upon login. I'll try deleting the acct and remakingit

Comment: You can also add multiple emails to a single account by editing `/etc/aliases`. [This](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3912056/Adding-Users-and-Aliases-for-Postfix.htm) may be of some help.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  I just also realized, there's no Inbox in my mail folder. These are the only ones that exist: nastylucas@quicksilver:~/mail$ ls
INBOX.Drafts  INBOX.Sent  INBOX.Trash

Comment: Got it. I'll check it out, I really appreciate your help with this.  I've been at it since about 3pm and it's driving me crazy.  Anyway, I'll post once I check out all the details.  I'm exhausted.